# Making some HTML elements behave as 'block' ones when mixed with inline elements inside an inline parent

Tags: css, inline, block

I'm trying to get an div with its display property set to inline (or inline-block if I want a margin) to behave correctly in IE (it does in most others).
My situation is this - imagine a workspace in which an item container contains inline items laid out in a horizontal fashion. These items can hold things like text, or images, but also be composite types, say for example a 'fraction', whose numerator and denominator are themselves item containers, containing more horizontal items.

So for example, I might have the HTML:

```
<div class='item-container'>
    <div id='statictext' class='item'>x = </div>

    <div id='fraction' class='item'>
        <div id='numerator' class='item-container'>...</div>
        <hr/>
        <div id='denominator' class='item-container'>...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Clearly, I don't want fixed width or height for an item or item-container, because they can contain nested content which will increase the amount of space needed (e.g. imagine an fraction inside another fraction), and similarly if I want the width of a static text 'item' to be just big enough to contain the text on one line, i.e. inline.

The problem I think is that it's hard to avoid putting block elements inside my inline 'item'/'item-container' elements, for example the `<hr>` in the fraction, or if I want say a menu bar at the top of an 'item' that uses the whole width after the width of the rest of the item's contents has been calculated. 
I know it's invalid syntax to put an actual block item inside an inline one, although setting the block element's display attribute to inline or inline-block makes things behave correctly in Firefox/Chrome at least. But alas, not in IE.

Is there an adequate fix?

EDIT: I actually used inline-block (with the appropriate IE hack) for 'item' and 'item-container' to get it to work spiffingly in Firefox et al, but IE still treats them as inline, which then subsequently gets converted into block because one of its children is a block.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use `<hr>`. You can draw a line using `text-decoration: underline` or using a bottom border or using an image (say, a one-pixel image stretched to the desired width). Then you can work with inline elements.

Comment: Thanks. I've endeavouring to make all internal elements inline, but it's somewhat annoying their isn't a cross-browser supported way of making elements fill whatever space is used. With the fraction line for example, using a border-bottom on the numerator or using text-decoration doesn't always yield the correct result, in cases where the denominator is wider than the numerator.